# Translation and meaning of an Ọṣun chant

Tags: translation, yoruba

I am hoping to find clarification on the correct spelling and meaning of the following song for Ọṣun:

- *Jowo gba mi se o ore, yeye Ọṣun (2x)*

  *A di di ndi (2x)*

  *Osun Sekese Oloo ya Iyun*

I'm told that Jowo means *please* and ore is *friend*. I know that *yeye* is mother.

[Google translates](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=yo&tl=en&text=gba%20mi%20se%20o%20ore) *Jowo gba mi se o ore* as *accept me friend*. Google translates *a di di ndi* to *we are the husband*, but *adi di ndi* as *exist*.

Looks like ṣekese means *immediately*, oloo means *fertile* and Iyun means *pregnancy*, so I'm leaning towards

- Ọṣun ṣekese oloo 'ya Iyun

With *'ya* referring to *Iya* or "mother".

So the overall meaning would be something like:

- Ọṣun, please accept me, friend.

  Exist, exist.

  Ọṣun the immediate fertile mother of pregnancy

Any more informed insight, correction, clarification most welcome.

Thank you and aṣe.

## UPDATE

It appears that "ṣe ke se" could mean *do it*.